# Does iPhone OS 3.0.1 ruin your development phone?

Tags: iphone

I updated my phone to 3.0.1.  While the phone works fine as a phone, [xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) organizer no longer knows the name of the phone.  It also says 3.0.1 is unsupported by this version of xcode.

I downloaded the latest version of xcode and OS (3.1).  Now, I'm trying to move my phone from 3.0.1 to 3.1.  I'm pressing option-restore in [iTunes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITunes) (does this bring in the beta OS?).  It tells me all the data on my phone will be erased.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of messing around (with much guidance from people here), I got some understanding of the OSX file system.  My files were not set up as expected (maybe because I upgraded XCode to 3.1).  If anyone else runs into the same issue, here's what you need to do:

1) Log into your Mac with an Admin account and launch the Terminal application (/Applications/Utilities)

2) Check to see where your system keeps files for supporting iPhone 3.0:

```
ls -l /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/
```

3) Look for a file like 3.0.  You may see "3.0" (like me), "3.0 (7A341)", or something else

4) Make a link so XCode looks for 3.0.1 in the 3.0 location.  Some examples:

```
ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0.1
ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0\ \(7A341\) /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0.1
```

5) Confirm this works by restarting XCode and opening the organizer

As Benjamin points out, do not upgrade to 3.1 unless really needed.

Answer (score 6):

Please execute the following and you will be fine, NO NEED TO RESTORE THE IPHONE,

1. Log into your Mac with an Admin account and launch the Terminal application
   (/Applications/Utilities)
2. Copy and paste the following (one) line into Terminal:

   > `ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0\ \(7A341\)
   >   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0.1`

make absolute sure that that you execute the ln -s command correctly and make certain you didn't get any errors. After the command executes correctly you should be able to do this:

```
ls -l /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0\ \(7A341\) /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0.1
```

and see this:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0.1 -> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0 (7A341)
```

Comment: tried this, but I see the same message in organizer after restarting xcode

Comment: make absolute sure that that you execute the ln -s command correctly and make certain you didn't get any errors. After the command executes correctly you should be able to do this:
ls -l /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0\ \\(7A341\\) /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0.1
and see this:
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0.1 -> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0 (7A341)

Comment: Not 100% sure what it reported when I originally copied the ln command.  Now, it says, "ln: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0.1: File exists".  And the ls command returns "No such file or directory
".  I've been a pc guy and this is new to me.

Comment: on the assumption I'm accidentally linking from an existing file, I tried copying that file to a new location (in preparation for deleting it).  The terminal reports it doesn't exist!

Comment: try ls -l /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0\ \\(7A341\\)

Comment: ls -l /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0\ \\(7A341\\) "no such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

No. Just type the following line into the terminal (make sure you are logged in as an admin):

ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0\ (7A341) /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0.1

I would *not* recommend updating to 3.1 unless there are specific 3.1 features that you would like to use in your app.

Comment: tried this, but I see the same message in organizer after restarting xcode