# iPhone app doesn't build crash reports

Tags: iphone, xcode

My app formerly created useful crash logs.  I synced my iPhone in the past and found crash logs in library/logs/CrashReporter

About a month ago, my app stopped creating crash reports.  When I first discovered this problem, I assumed it was due to memory corruption (a possibility in my app).

I just created a new project and added a crash to it.

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, 
// typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array removeObjectAtIndex:-1];

  [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

This app does not create a crash report either.

Ideas I've started to explore:

1. My phone is corrupted (tried restoring - somehow I brought it to the state from a few months ago)
2. My XCode is corrupt (tried reinstalling, but current download demands Snow Leopard - and I can't upgrade to Snow Leopard online).  This seems possible - I may have messed with device support around a month ago (similar to [Does iPhone OS 3.0.1 ruin your development phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224867/does-iphone-os-3-0-1-ruin-your-development-phone) )
3. The location for crash logs has somehow moved.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked in XCode's Organizer? Ctrl-Command-O

There you should find all your Device's Logs

Comment: The logs are there! I'm not sure why they're not where I expected on mac/pc, but this helps a ton.

Comment: Looks like is solved then. Please accept this as the bounty answer.