# iOS crash logs printed to console

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, debugging

My problem appeared when iOS 6 was introduced, but now seems to affect 5.1.1 too.

When the app crashes, the log is printed to the 'Console' and no 'Device Logs' is saved. This is frustrating in so many ways:

- console view is too short and all I can see is the log's tail,
- copy/paste doesn't work, save to file... produces garbage, it is unusable,
- there is no way to preserve logs, symbolicate it, or do anything.

It may be worth mentioning, that we work with accessories and have no way to connect debugger at the same time.

An idea how to fix this would save my day, but any decent workaround will be good too.

Thank you

EDIT: 'Console' and 'Device Logs' are the ones I get in the Organizer.

Comment: press cmd+7 and you will get history of all you builds. Here you can see log messages that you need.

Comment: But only if the debugger was connected during execution. This doesn't really help me.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691427/iphone-app-doesnt-build-crash-reports

Comment: Thank you, but this is where are used to see my crashed logs, but can't anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I am aware of will require a little bit of setting up. Once setup you will have access to the full log, even since reboot time, and you can save it for later.

You need a jailbroken device. From within Cydia install the packages called `syslogd to /var/log/syslog` and `OpenSSH`. Follow the OpenSSH-tutorial on the Cydia start page (half way down). The `syslogd`-package has no tutorial but the install procedure is the same. After installing `syslogd` reboot the device.

The logs are written to `/var/log/syslog`. Use `ssh` from a terminal on your development mac to log into the device and view/tail the logs. You can `scp` the logs back to your development machine or can use CyberDuck or similar to get them off the device.

The logs will grow in size and I am not sure if there is something limiting, so keep an eye on file size. A friendly

`> /var/log/syslog`

from time to time should do.

PS: There is also a `MobileTerminal` package on Cydia. It will allow you to view the log directly from the device, without ssh'ing in from a second computer

Comment: I wanted to avoid jailbreaking a company's device, but I can't see any other way now. As there were no better answers, I will accept this one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In latest version of iOS, the following worked for me...

```
//This method will be invoked before crash occurs
 void onUncaughtException(NSException* exception)
 {
      //Print whatever you want to print before, I have print the info from exception
      MDDDebugLog(@"Reason for crash : %@", [exception reason]);
      MDDDebugLog(@"Name of the crash : %@", [exception name]);
      MDDDebugLog(@"Stack trace of the crash: %@", [exception   callStackSymbols]); 
 }

//Print crash log in file

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    //Assign a method which will be invoked before crash occurs
      NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&onUncaughtException); 
  }
```